# Without microphone jack, how to use MacBook Pro 13 inch for having a skype conversation?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I recently found out that the Headphone jack for the Macbook Pro 13 inch doubles up as the microphone jack. In that case, how to use the Macbook for having a Skype/Gtalk conversation (while ensuring privacy using headphones) ?

This is the only issue I've found with this model, and I hate to have to look elsewhere due to this seemingly simple issue...

Comment: I must say i'm puzzled by your privacy issue. While using headphones indeed ensures, that people around you cannot hear what the person at the other end says, using an additional microphone rather than the internal one does *not* make people around you not hear you anymore :))

Comment: Well, I should have closed the question as soon as I had found there was a built-in microphone (I assumed I'd always have to use the jack for the mike, and hence leave my speakers on !!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unified line out / line in jack on the 13 inch MacBook line will take any headphone/microphone combination that works with iPhone and other iOS devices. You can also [use many bluetooth headsets with your Mac](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Bluetooth/1.0/en/blu26.html).

Keep in mind, you are not getting much extra privacy putting the mic close to your mouth as the Mac's built in microphone is quite sensitive and most people are going to hear you equally well whether you have a microphone six inches or 24 inches from your mouth.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using an adaptor like

http://www.instructables.com/id/133quot-Macbook-Pro-HeadphoneMic-Adapter/

or, use an iPhone headset

Edit: There seems to be some confusion on whether this works or not, so please verify it before making a purchase

If you are open to using a USB device, try something like: [http://www.amazon.com/Griffin-Technology-iMic-Audio-Device/dp/B000BVV2IC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BVV2IC)

Comment: Upvote for USB suggestion. Most people don't think of them.

Comment: Much love for the Griffin iMic - especially when you don't want/can't use the built in jack with a headset that includes mic and headphones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could possibly use a mic in the audio in/out jack, and get a bluetooth or usb headset. Or buy a mic adapter designed for macbook pros that includes both a headphone and microphone jack, (two jacks). If you're searching on amazon or best buy make sure to clarify it's for macbook pros, because some are designed for pcs only.